# Abstract class, how to call function print

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

I have a problem, I have this base class:

```
class A{
public:
    /*...*/
    virtual void print() = 0;
};
```

And here I make one class which inherits from class "A"

```
class B : public A{
private:
    double a;
public:
    /*...*/
    B(double _a) : a(_a){ }
    void print() override{
        cout << a<<'\n';
    }
};
```

And I use:

```
int main(){
/*...*/ 
std::vector<A*> vec; 
/* ... Here I added new object */
vec.push_back(new B(2)); 

for(__typeof(vec.begin()) it = (vec.begin()); it!= vec.end(); it++){
}
   //How to using and display function print which is declared inside class B
}
```

Question: How to call function `print` which is declared inside class B?

I have tried using following method but this notation don't give me a good result:

```
vec.front()->print();
```

Comment: What's wrong with `it->print()`?

Comment: this notation `it->print();` doesn't work.

Comment: @meernet how doesn't it work? Also, why is there a comma after the parameter list in B's constructor?

Comment: @MrLister You need to dereference both the iterator and the contained pointer.

Comment: @Mr Lister, Yes, but I don't know why, compilator tell me that i should using -> but if I using this notation i have a error

Comment: @MrLister comma, when I sign code, I go wrong.

Comment: Why `__typeof()` ? Isn't `auto` good enough ?

Comment: Don't forget a virtual destructor.

Comment: @NeilKirk, /*...*/ ->  here I have

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `main` just needs to be like this:

```
int main(){

    std::vector<A*> vec; 
    /* ... Here I added new object */
    vec.push_back(new B(2)); 

    for(std::vector<A*>::iterator it = vec.begin(), end = vec.end(); it != end; ++it){
        (*it)->print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note how the iterator is dereferenced inside the loop.

Comment: Ok, I found my mistake before, However Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your loop you need to dereference the iterator and the contained pointer. So write something like:

```
(*it)->print();
```

But you might want to consider a C++11 ranged-based for loop instead:

```
for (auto ptr : vec)
    ptr->print();
```